# java http apache client does not receive the content

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache client libs for http client to post some data to my server.

Below is the code, I get the status line response, but I am not getting the contents.
But on wireshark I could see server is responding the with few contents, such content type, location etc. for my code I am getting the following output.

```
Status :: HTTP/1.1 201 Created Content null
```

Pls help me to find out where I have gone wrong to read the content , do I need to some proxy related settings ?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String line = "";      String status = "";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/msg");
try {

  HttpEntity e = new StringEntity("POSTING TO SERVER FOR TESTING");
  post.setEntity(e);


  HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new
  InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  status = response.getStatusLine().toString() ;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(" Status :: "+ status + " Content " + line);
```

Comment: The reason for `Status :: HTTP/1.1 201 Created Content null` is because the last value assigned to `line` is `null`.  The response may not have any content.  You can use the API to examine the headers as you need

Comment: What was printed *before* the 'Status:' line? That's your content. I suspect this is just poor observation on your part, not a genuine problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `Status :: HTTP/1.1 201 Created Content null` is because the last value assigned to `line` is `null` (it's how you broke out of the loop).  The response may not have any content.  You can use the API to examine the headers as you need

Take a look at [How to get headers? (java,httpclient 4.X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846886/how-to-get-headers-java-httpclient-4-x) for an example