# 406 Not Acceptable while uploading image to a subdomain

Tags: java, file-upload

I am trying to upload file to a url for that I am using this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;

public class UploadIt{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s=uploadFile(new File("C://paid.png"), "http://abc.xyz.com");
        System.out.println("val is "+s);
    }
public static String uploadFile(File resourceUrl,String url) throws HttpException, IOException{
    File f = resourceUrl;
    PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod(url);
    Part[] parts = {new FilePart(f.getName(), f)};
    filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
    String resultUUid=null;
    resultUUid = filePost.getResponseBodyAsString();
    filePost.releaseConnection();
        System.out.println(" status "+status );
    return resultUUid;
}
}
```

From [source](https://samindaw.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/how-to-post-or-upload-a-file-to-a-url-or-servelet-using-java/).

It is giving error

```
 status 406
val is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource / could not be found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

How to resolve this problem
my directory has permission 755

Comment: On what basis do you make the assumption that you can upload a file using a POST request on http://abc.xyz.com (Alphabet)?

Comment: abc.xyz is only name given I want to upload it to my subdomain

Comment: You have the check the log files of the application that receives the transfer to see why it did not accept your request. It's there where you can get the information from. If there is nothing yet in the server logfile, debug the server application to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the directory permissions. it may be a restriction on the  Mime types accepted by the server  - have a look here http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

> Accept: The MIME types accepted by the client. For example, a browser may only accept back types of data (HTML files, GIF files etc.) it knows how to process.

maybe you could print the response headers as well for further debugging

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846886/how-to-get-headers-java-httpclient-4-x - dump the response headers using the tips given in that answer

Comment: IT is showing HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx admin
Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 11:19:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 325
X-Cache: HIT from Backend